# Kubernetes dashboard installation issue in ubuntu

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-16.04, kubectl

I'm facing issue when I'm accessing kubernetes dashboard, when I start  it using the command `kubectl proxy --address kmaster --port 8058` but when am accessing it I'm facing unauthorised issue but after I'm adding --disable-filter=true in the command, I'm able to access but when I gave the irrelevant token in the Kubernetes Dashboard  its throwing error like 'Authentication failed. Please try again.' but when I gave the relevant token nothing is happening in the screen remains the same with no further process.

Comment: are you using minikube? how did you install the dashboard?

Comment: https://www.edureka.co/blog/install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu
I follow this steps

Comment: Have you tried to add `--accept-hosts '.*'` parameter?

Comment: Yes I tried but still same

Comment: Have you tried `kubectl proxy` without parameters? Please check https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/